# Yetanotherforum basic integration onto website

Tags: c#, asp.net, yetanotherforum

I've got the forum setup on my ASP.net website fine, works great!

I want to use their membership system as my central user system on my site though.

I basically want to be able to tell if a user is logged in or not.  IE, best case scenario, on my custom Master page I just have a:

```
if(UserIsLoggedIn){
    Response.Write(LoggedInUserName);
}
```

Don't really know how to go about getting that though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAF.NET uses well documented ASP.NET membership.

Try:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();

if (user != null)
{
   // user is logged in...
   Response.Write(user.UserName);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jaben, sorry if it came off as aggressive, I did actually ask in your forum first but only one user was helping me and he couldn't really answer me.

Comment: Sorry about that, Tom. If I had seen your post, I would have responded to it.

Comment: no worries, I love the initial impression of YAF by the way, it's miles ahead of any other .net forum and I look forward to running it on my site!  I've edited original question so my misunderstanding wont reflect badly on you.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error?

P.S. It's `Response.Write()`, **capitalized.**

Comment: No error, I just have no idea where to begin on working out if a user is logged in or not.